# Vertical distance control of <div> if it spills to next line, in mobile dynamic website

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I am building a mobile version of a website.
The site displays pictures with captions underneath.
The problem I am having is that, on mobile version, when the next line of picture is displayed, it overwrites the caption above it.
My question is is there a way to control how a div displays its content if it spills to next line, so that I can give it enough space from the contents above it.

I know I have not included any codes but any push in the right direction will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: specify image height in media query for mobile version..

Comment: Without knowing your existing HTML structure & CSS it's hard to offer any definitive advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without looking at the code, but I would suggest wrapping image and caption into a div like this:

```
<div class="image-container>
    <img src="yourImage"/>
    <div> Some caption </div>
</div
```

and in CSS:

```
.image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Worked a charm. Thanks. simple and effective.